# Optimization of Like Query

Tags: mysql

One quick question:-

Can this following query can be further optimized?

```
select
    x.id, y.first_name,y.last_name, y.unit_no, y.address_1,y.city
from
    customers x
INNER JOIN
    people y
        on x.person_id = y.person_id
WHERE
        x.deleted = '0'
    AND (
            y.city LIKE '%mil%'
        OR  y.first_name LIKE '%mil%'
        OR  y.address_1 LIKE '%mil%'
        OR  y.address_2 LIKE '%mil%'
        OR  y.phone_number LIKE '%mil%'
    )
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: probs better for Code review SE - this question is off-topic here. Also just for readability, it's best to drop each statement to a new line

Comment: Hi @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, can u suggest ?

Comment: I don't use MySQL, but it does appear to have FULLTEXT search abilities : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Show the table definitions.

Comment: @strawberry Because most of the questions don't need expert knowledge of MySQL. This one needed more than I have actual experience of, so I commented. Others I can actually answer.

Comment: Aside from removing the inverted commas around '0', the best thing you do is probably to restructure your schema such that '%x' searches (as opposed to 'x%' searches) were not required. But yeah, alternatively, look at FULLTEXT indexes as mentioned by MB

Comment: thanks @Strawberry

Comment: I just looked at https://hackernoon.com/dont-waste-your-time-with-mysql-full-text-search-61f644a54dfa which says FULL TEXT is of no use. I need clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like uses wildcards only, and isn't all that powerful.

Full text allows much more complex searching, including And, Or, Not, even similar sounding results (SOUNDEX) and many more items.

I started looking at the FREETEXT() and related Full Text search items to help get a better understanding of what is available.

Ok please do the following steps and try the query and I got it running in 0.008 Seconds.

**Step 1:** Enable FULL TEXT for columns: first name, last name and address.

**Step 2:** Modify the WHERE condition of the query with MATCH and AGAINST.

**Step 3:** Add LIKE condition to the query.

After columns have been added to a full-text index, users and applications can run full-text queries on the text in the columns. These queries can search for any of the following:

- One or more specific words or phrases (simple term)
- A word or a phrase where the words begin with specified text (prefix term)
- Inflectional forms of a specific word (generation term)
- A word or phrase close to another word or phrase (proximity term)
- Synonymous forms of a specific word (thesaurus)
- Words or phrases using weighted values (weighted term)

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT(x.first_name,' ',x.last_name) AS name, x.phone_number, 
                       x.unit_no, x.address_1, x.city, y.person_id 
   FROM people y INNER JOIN customers x 
     ON x.id = y.id 
     WHERE y.deleted = '0' 
     AND MATCH(x.first_name) AGAINST ('mark zuker') OR 
         MATCH(x.last_name) AGAINST ('mark zuker') OR 
         MATCH(x.address_1) AGAINST ('mark zuker') OR 
         x.first_name LIKE 'mark zuker%' OR 
         x.last_name LIKE 'mark zuker%' OR 
         x.phone_number LIKE '%mark zuker%' OR 
         x.unit_no LIKE 'mark zuker%' OR 
         x.address_1 LIKE '%mark zuker%' OR 
         x.city LIKE '%mark zuker%' LIMIT 0,1500;
```

**Compare Full-Text Search queries to the LIKE predicate**

In contrast to full-text search, the LIKE Transact-SQL predicate works on character patterns only. Also, you cannot use the LIKE predicate to query formatted binary data. Furthermore, a LIKE query against a large amount of unstructured text data is much slower than an equivalent full-text query against the same data. A LIKE query against millions of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a full-text query can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending on the number of rows that are returned.

**Which one is faster LIKE or FULLTEXT?** Based on my experience, LIKE can be much faster than the FULLTEXT. So, I have used FULLTEXT to particular columns alone in your case.

Comment: Thanks @Keynes, It worked much faster than before! The case with my query was that it returned from morethan 50000 records

Comment: yeah may be.. you could add FULLTEXT to whatever columns you need to ..